# Matplotlib graph displaying aggregate functions in a strange manner

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I've faced with the following problem while trying to display data from a DataFrame with Matplotlib. The idea is to build a linear graph where Y-axis is the mean of score for each gamer and the X-axis is the number of shots performed. I have applied aggregate functions to the data in my DataFrame but the resulting graph doesn't look as I have expected.
Here is what I've done so far:

The DataFrame

```
    Score      Gamer       Shots
a    5.0       gamer1        7   
b    3.0       gamer2        2  
c    2.5       gamer1        8   
d    7.1       gamer3        9
e    1.8       gamer3        2
f    2.2       gamer3        1
```

The Plot

```
plt.title('Plot 1', size=14)
plt.xlabel('Number of Shots', size=14)
plt.ylabel('Mean Score', size=14)
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='g', linestyle='-')
x = df[['gamer','shots']].groupby(['gamer']).count()
y = df[['gamer','score']].groupby(['gamer']).mean()
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need something like this:

```
In [52]: df.groupby('Gamer').agg({'Score':'mean','Shots':'count'}).plot()
Out[52]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xb41e710>
```

[image]

corresponding data:

```
In [54]: df.groupby('Gamer').agg({'Score':'mean','Shots':'count'})
Out[54]:
        Score  Shots
Gamer
gamer1   3.75      2
gamer2   3.00      1
gamer3   3.70      3
```

**UPDATE:**

> I need just a single line plot for displaying the dependency of mean
>   score of a gamer (Y-axis) on the number of shots(X-axis)

```
In [90]: df.groupby('Gamer').agg({'Score':'mean','Shots':'count'}).set_index('Shots').plot()
Out[90]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xbe749b0>
```

[image]

**UPDATE2:**

```
In [155]: g = df.groupby('Gamer').agg({'Score':'mean','Shots':'count'}).sort_values('Shots')

In [156]: x,y = g['Shots'], g['Score']

In [157]: plt.plot(x, y)
Out[157]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xbdbf668>]
```

[image]

Comment: Well I need just a single line plot for displaying the dependency of mean score of a gamer (Y-axis) on the number of shots(X-axis).

Comment: When trying to display the graph for the table generated by `df.groupby('Gamer').agg({'Score':'mean','Shots':'count'})` I want to use the mathplotlib design like in my post. So then I do: plt.plot(x='Shots', y='Score') and getting an empty plot.